# Pull data from 1 worksheet into another automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, excel-auto-fill

I need a way to get information from worksheets `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`, etc. into the Summary Worksheet.  Each worksheet Name will be listed in the Summary Worksheet, column A and in each worksheet in F1 (not shown in image).  As new worksheets are added, and added to the Summary Worksheet, the Summary Worksheet will be sorted by column A and the items in Column A will end up shifting line numbers. (Ex. If item A1B1 was added to Summary Worksheet, column A after DDD, then Summary Worksheet was sorted on column A, A1B1 would be on top.  See Example, column Q below.)

`X` = A blank field in Column O where the formula will go.

`Y` = The data I want. A Sum (calculated number) within the worksheet and will be in cell C3.

I would prefer this to be a formula that goes in the Summary Worksheet, column O, pulls the worksheet name (automatically) from column A, goes to the applicable worksheet and grabs the info.  This way I can pull the formula down as the spreadsheet grows.
So the formula for O1 would go something like, and I know this is wrong:

```
=IF(A1=””,””,???($C3, [something magical here-pull worksheet name from A1]!$C$1:$D$4,1,0))
```

Summary
[image: Corrected Example Summary]

Worksheets
[image: Worksheets AAA, BBB & CCC]

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear, because in the sheet `BBB` your `Y` is in `D3` and not `C3`.
From the text I understand you need the value from `C3`.
Generally, you need to use INDIRECT function e.g.

```
=IF(A1="","",INDIRECT(A1&"!C3"))
```

or

```
=IF(A1="","",INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!C3"))
```

The second version (with single quotes) is necessary when sheet name contains space or other special character or is a number. If your sheet names are simple texts (letters & digits only) you can use shorter version.

Comment: You're correct, I missed the Y in D3, sorry about that & I fixed it above.  You gave the answer I've tried multiple times & I get the same answer with your answer as with mine, a blank field.  This is in my "Real" worksheet.  Then I decided to create a new, blank worksheet, like the examples above, & it worked fine, so my real worksheet is the issue.  Wish I’d thought about that a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the answers provided by MGonet are correct, listed below.  Turns out there is some hidden issue in my worksheet that is preventing it from working.

```
=IF(A1="","",INDIRECT(A1&"!C3"))
```

or

```
=IF(A1="","",INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!C3"))
```